# How to write bytes in the middle of a file in android/java

Tags: java, file

How to write bytes in the middle (specific position) of a file in android or java without overwriting any data?

**Example**
If I have file of size *500kb*, I wish to add 512 bytes of data after *200kb*

This question has been marked as *duplicate* but the referred question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181408/best-way-to-write-bytes-in-the-middle-of-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Define file. Is it a text file that you wish to add some characters or a raw binary file?

Comment: @JoanColmenero: but this will overwrite file content, which the OP does not want

Comment: @GeorgeD - It could be of any format. The idea behind this is to add security. Adding _garbage_ data while uploading the file so that only a selected application can open the file. The selected application would remove those _garbage_ bytes in order to make the file accessible

Comment: @JoanColmenero - I saw that and just like cello mentioned, it would overwrite my data.

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy First, there's no security to gain here. So if you want security, use something else. If you *still* want to insert garbage between the server and client, you could just write the first 200 kb of the file, then write 512 b garbage to the server stream, then continue to write the file from there. No need to modify the original file on the client for this.

Comment: @haraldK - I get that. The thing is, if I insert the garbage at a specific point in the middle, only I would know what to remove and how much to remove. That's the security. Adding in the beginning would cause the same issue I was having before.

Comment: Do you think "This is SLIGHTLY LESS insecure" is much harder to read than "This is insecure"? ;-) Yes, you make it harder to open the file for people who have no clue. But people with a clue will figure out what's going on. In any case, it's your call. I'll leave you to it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: you can't. you can skip to 200kb, but then you need to read the rest of the file, e.g. in a ByteBuffer, go back to 200kb-position, write your 512 bytes and then write the 300kb from the ByteBuffer again. By design, file content cannot be "shifted", only read and (over-)written, so you have to do the shifting yourself.

Comment: What about `RandomAccessFile` ? Does that let me **seek** to a specific position in the file?

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Yes, but it doesn't solve your problem. While seek can potentially be faster than skip, you still need to copy the remaining data forward.

Comment: @haraldK - What about the solution present [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677170/write-bytes-into-a-file-without-erasing-existing-bytes?lq=1) ?

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy I think that is what cello tried to tell you...

Comment: @haraldK - Okay, I had a question about that. I am dealing with various file types here (videos, pdf, images, etc.). Would there be enough buffer size available in case of a video file?